# Bitwise operation on int type

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I've the following code:

```
int x = 1340;
printf("%d\n", x << 2);
printf("%d\n", x >> 1);
```

1340 binary number is:

```
00000000|00000000|00000101|00111100
```

So from my understanding the first print should be the integer equivalent of:

```
00000000|00000000|00010100|11110000
```

Which is 5360, and it's right, however the seconds print should be the integer equivalent of

```
00000000|00000000|00001010|01111000
```

When I calculate it, I get that it's suppose to print 2680, but when I run the program, it prints 670. It might be a dumb question, but I can't realize what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I'd recommend using `%.8X` for `printf`, so that you can map bits to digits 1:1 (because there is such a mapping for hex digits).

Comment: @RonSadikov If any of the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're downshifting the original number by 1, not the result of the upshift operation. There aren't any assignments in your program, so `x` never changes value.

Answer (score 4):

The `>>` and `<<` are not modifying the x, so each shift is performed on the same value, not the result of the previous shift. If you want to retain the result of previous shift you should perform an assignment operation either `x= x<<2` or `x<<=2` which are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean to use this operator `<<=`, which will shift and assign the result simultaneously, so this must work

```
int x = 1340;
printf("%d\n", x <<= 2);
printf("%d\n", x >>= 1);
```

the `<<` or `>>` operators by themselves do not modify the value of `x`.